# Elder Scrolls Online doesn't allow textures above "Medium"

Tags: hardware, the-elder-scrolls-online

I haven't been able to find any information on google about this, but I recently nabbed the beta for ESO, and decided to fiddle with the settings. For some reason the overall **Graphics** setting only allows me to select **Minimum**, **Low** and **Medium**. The same goes for the **Texture** tab, though there are individual things that let me choose **Ultra** (such as Water Reflections).

I'm not sure if this is a bug, or if ESO does some checking and limits the settings you're allowed to select based on your hardware. Interestingly, pressing the **Reset to Defaults** sets everything to **High**, but I can't do that manually.

My PC specs are about in line with the recommended settings.

- **OS** - Windows 7 32bit
- **CPU** - Intel Core 2 Quad - 2.4 ghz
- **GPU** - Radeon HD 6850
- **RAM** - 4GB

Between the behavior of the Reset button and the fact that my specs are very close to the Recommended specs, I'd be surprised if this behavior is intentional, but I really have no clue. Is this a problem with my hardware, or should I be submitting a bug report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your specs, you may not have enough VRAM to support going above medium textures.

Comment: It's a frustrating way for them to handle it. I wish they would have said something to that effect on the UI. Used this as the excuse to finally buy parts for a new computer, anyway.

Comment: It saves the user frustration by not letting them try to use too much VRAM.  The Titanfall beta let me try to use more VRAM than I had and it caused some frustrating lag until I read the fine print.

Comment: Without the notification that it's missing settings because of my hardware, it really looks like a glitch. Not knowing if it's a glitch or intentional is pretty bad UI design. But that's not a topic for this site. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

No... (in case anyone else comes across this.) Its a bug that's STILL around.
Go to bottom of settings window and click default. It will then show all the unseen settings. Will also set them automatically to high if you have a high end card.